# Tree Math Formula UVA

Tags: math, tree

A cat wears a hat if and only if it has N cats in its hat.
There is exactly one cat that is not inside any other cat’s hat.
If there are M cats without hats, how many cats are there?

I tried this problem following is my code snippet is below .

```
LL dfs(int n,int m,LL sum){
    if(m<n){
        return -1; // If not possible
    }
    if(m==n){
        return sum+n+1;
    }
    return  dfs(n,(m/n)+m%n,sum+n*(LL)floor(m*1.0/n));
}
```

I handled case n==1 and m==1 , explicitly .

Not able to get it where i am going wrong .

Link : [catsproblem](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1434)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is unnecessarily complicated--there is a straightforward formula for the answer and your recursion is not needed.

You are correct that if N=1 (each hat has one cat) then M=1 (there can be only one cat without a hat) and the total number of cats is unknown.

In the general case N>1, if there are no cats with hats then there must be only the "exactly one cat" without a hat. So at the start, that makes 1 cat without hats. Whenever we add a hat on a cat, that adds N new hatless cats inside that hat but removes that old cat from being hatless, so each hat adds a count of N-1 to the hatless cats. Therefore if H is the number of cats with hats, the number of cats without hats is

```
M = 1 + H * (N - 1)
```

Solving for H,

```
H = (M - 1) / (N - 1)
```

So the total number of cats is

```
T = M + H
  = M + (M - 1) / (N - 1)
```

Note that this does not depend on the structure of the cat-tree. This is a feasible answer if that last expression is an integer and is infeasible otherwise.

Here is simple Python 3.x code printing the total number of cats--I'll leave the parsing and other printing to you. If you don't like the double-layer of `if`s, my code can easily be restructured to be more flat.

```
def print_total_cats(n, m):
    if n == 1:
        if m == 1:
            print('Multiple')
        else:
            print('Impossible')
    else:
        if (m - 1) % (n - 1) != 0:
            print('Impossible')
        else:
            print(m + (m - 1) // (n - 1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rory Daulton sir :) because of you i came to constant time complexity , mine is O(log base n(m) ) time complexity .

Comment: I tried to upvote your answer but as i have rating which is less then 15 ,that is why i am not able to upvote your answer , thanks for your sincere effort .once i have rating > 15 will upvote your answer .

Answer (score 1):

One case i missed that is if m==1 answer should be 1 , i handled it explicitly .

```
LL dfs(int n,int m,LL sum){
if(m<n){
    return -1;
}
if(m==n){
    return sum+n+1;
}
return  dfs(n,(m/n)+m%n,sum+n*(LL)floor(m*1.0/n));}

int main(){
int n,m;
LL a;
while(scanf("%d%d",&n,&m)&&(n||m)){
    cout<<n<<" "<<m<<" ";
if(n==1 && m==1){
    cout<<"Multiple\n";
    continue;
}
if(n==1 && m>=2){
    cout<<"Impossible\n";
    continue;
}
 if(m==1)
     a=1;
 else
    a=dfs(n,m,0);
 if(a==-1){
     cout<<"Impossible\n";
 }  else
    cout<<a<<"\n";
}
return 0;}
```